# Dynamic variable name of scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, syntax

I try to define a dynamic variable name in a angularjs foreach, like this :

```
angular.forEach($scope.posts, function (item) {
    // counter increment
    counter++;

    var idPage = 'feed' + counter;

    FeedService.parseFeed(url).then(function(res) {
        $scope.window[idPage] = res.data.responseData.feed.entries;
    });

});
```

so, it's doesn't work and i have this error : `Cannot set property 'feed1' of undefined`

what's the correct syntax ?

Comment: Could you provide a plnkr?

Comment: $scope['feed1'] = 'test';
                console.log($scope.feed1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your $scope object have a `window` property? If yes, go with Maxim's answer. If not, try this:

```
angular.forEach($scope.posts, function (item) {
    // counter increment
    counter++;

    var idPage = 'feed' + counter;

    FeedService.parseFeed(url).then(function(res) {
        $scope[idPage] = res.data.responseData.feed.entries;
    });

});
```

Edit:

Working plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/eVLJKIspLwKPCYAg7L8w?p=preview